# Have issues with collision detection in pygame

Tags: pygame, collision, pacman

```
def movement(self):
    
    prevX = self.x
    prevY = self.y

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if key[pygame.K_w]:
        self.y -= 32
    elif key[pygame.K_s]:
        self.y += 32
    elif key[pygame.K_a]:
        self.x -= 32
    elif key[pygame.K_d]:       
        self.x += 32

    x = int(self.x / 32)
    y = int(self.y / 32)

    if TEXT_LEVEL[x][y] != "=":
        print("wall")
        print(x,y)
        print(TEXT_LEVEL[x][y])
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x, self.y)
        self.x = prevX
        self.y = prevY
```

So I have an array that stores the map as a text file as such:

```
============.===============
=..........=...............=
=..........=...............=
=...........*..............=
=....===============.......=
=....=.....................=
=....=.............=.......=
.....===============........
=..................*.......=
=..........................=
=....===============.......=
=....*.............*.......=
=........=====.............=
= .........................=
============.===============
```

And what I'm doing is checking if the current position my sprite is in matches to the coordinates of a wall. If it does I reset the x and y and don't update its location. For some reason, this is not working and I'm stuck as to why it's failing.

The full project can be found on my github if anything needs to be referenced: https://github.com/rob-roibu/Pac-man

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `self.rect.topleft` after changing `self.x` and `self.y`:

```py
self.x = prevX
self.y = prevY
self.rect.topleft = (self.x, self.y)
```